# Angular2 custom directive issues

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

Mkay, I was following a tutorial online, [this one](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/10/creating-a-rating-directive-in-angular-2/), to be percise, the result of which was a directive as such:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'rating',
})

@View({
  template: `
      <span tabindex="0">
          <template NgFor="#val of range" #index="index">
              <span class="sr-only">(*)</span>
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          </template>
     </span>
 `,
  directives: [NgFor]
})

export class Rating {
    private range:Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

Seeing various errors here:

1. NgFor is not defined
2. If I import NgFor, then core_1.View is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `@View()` was removed in `beta.10`. Move the parameters to `@Component()` instead
- `NgFor` is part of `CORE_DIRECTIVES` no need to add them to `directives: []` anymore (was required in older versions)
- the `ngFor` syntax in your template was kind of a mix of shorthand and full syntax

1) directly applied to a tag (shorthand)

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">...</li>
```

2) using a wrapping `<template>` tag (full)

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items" let-i="index"><li>...</li></template>
```

See also [**NgFor**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgFor-directive.html)

**corrected code**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'rating',
  template: `
      <span tabindex="0">
          <template ngFor let-val [ngForOf]="range" let-index="index">
              <span class="sr-only">(*)</span>
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
          </template>
     </span>
 `,
  directives: []
})

export class Rating {
    private range:Array<number> = [1,2,3,4,5];
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't notice that !

Comment: You have already covered all points. Now there is now meaning to come up with a new answer ;-) So, I edited your answer with my updates :-)